# Logging log4net internal errors in windows event logs

Tags: c#, log4net

Currently i am logging log4net internal errors into text file

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="true">
    <listeners>
      <add
         name="textWriterTraceListener"
         type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
         initializeData="C:\local\log4netinfo.txt" />
    </listeners>
  </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Is there any way to log to windows event log ?

Comment: [EventLogTraceListener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlogtracelistener(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible.
According to the [FAQ](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#internalDebug),

> Internal debugging messages are written to the console and to the
>   System.Diagnostics.Trace system